# Use JSONPath to set a value in an array

Tags: php, json, jsonpath

I'm trying to process some decoded json data using the PHP implementation of JSONPath (http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

I'm fine with using an expression to FIND data in the decoded JSON, but I'd like to be able to SET data using a JSONPath expression. Has anyone been able to do this in PHP using JSONPath, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this implementation of JSONPath does not support set operations.

I've written a simple function that can be added to jsonPath.php to add this functionality. I've pasted it here in case it might be of use to anyone else:

```
/**
 * @param array  $obj       Decoded json file to alter
 * @param string $expr      JSONPath expression (http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
 * @param mixed  $value     Value to set all matching entries to
 */
function jsonPathSet(&$obj, $expr, $value)
{
    $paths = jsonPath($obj, $expr, array('resultType' => 'PATH'));
    $jsonPath = new JsonPath();

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $p = $jsonPath->normalize($path);
        $keys = explode(';', $p);

        $current = &$obj;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if($key=='$') {
                continue;
            } else if (is_array($current)) {
                $current = &$current[$key];
            } else {
                $current = &$current->$key;
            }
        }
        $current = $value;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Mike Brant for the suggestions!

Comment: Glad to see you came up with a solution. You might consider adding it as a method to the JsonPath object itself and submitting it back to the libraru maintainer for future use by others. It would be nice to have something like `$jsonPath->set($expr, $value)` as method signature which would operate on current JsonPath object.

Answer (score 1):

In briefly looking at the documentation, it would appear that JSONPath doesn't support set operations.  If one were so inclined, I would imagine that you could modify JSONPath to optionally return an array of pointers (i.e. object references) as a `resultType` such that you could operate on the values directly.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected but I was hoping this was not the case! I'll see if I can have a go at updating it.

Comment: @JMac Alternatively, one might also be able to implement a more brute force set method within the library.  It honestly might end up being similar or better performance-wise to building a set of references and then operating against that set.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions, I've posted one solution in another answer.